Difficult shifting gears
I have iveco eurocargo 180e280 truck, I replaced the pressure plate, afterwards the gears became difficult to shift. When I bleed the clutch the gears becomes soft to shift which is normal. But in no time it becomes difficult shifting  which calls for bleeding the clutch again. What could be the problem

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked for any leaks in the clutch hydraulic system? Do you ride the clutch when you drive?
